# Rechargeable battery for PI 3 and LCD

Tags: pi-3, battery

Currently working with a PI 3 and a 10 inch LCD, but as of right now I have 2 power cable, one for the PI and one for the LCD.

I'm looking for a way to power the PI and the LCD with a rechargeable battery and only use 1 cable to charge the battery and power it once plugged in.

Any recommendation on if I can find something out there that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of portable batteries out there that are capable of powering both a Pi and and LCD screen. I can't say I have ever come across a rechargeable battery that uses anything other than a single power cable to charge it. If you want to power multiple USB devices off a single USB port a powered USB hub will suffice. There is also the possibility of using a screen which connects to the GPIO port on the Pi

Comment: Beware that most USB powerbanks will probably undervolt a Pi 3 due to the way they handle current surges.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a link to the LCD panel you're using?